# Avoid add to cart for specific product categories if user is unlogged in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

In Woocommerce, I am trying to disable specific product categories to be added to the cart for users that aren't logged in. i'm looking for a solution the last couple of days and after frustrated deleting the last code I found this but also doesn't do the job.

I'm using a certain plugin (TZ product tabs) to show products on other pages (so not only on the category and product page (this i know how to disable))

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );

function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
    // replace a_category and another_category with the slugs of the categories you'd like to have the button removed from
    if( is_product_category( array( 'gekoelde-bier', 'bierkoerier'))) { 
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );            
    // add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', false );
    }
}
```

Referenced from https://gist.github.com/rynaldos/560c621714b9680433cddf18e6a50305

My best guess is to check the category of the product when the "add to cart" button is pressed and based on that the product can be added to the cart or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditional tag `is_product_category()` only target product category archive pages. Instead you can use WordPress conditional function [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term).

> There is **2 ways to avoid specific products being added to cart** for no logged user…

**1) Using Add to cart validation hook:**

```
// Avoid add to cart conditionally
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'avoid_add_to_cart_conditionally', 20, 3 );
function avoid_add_to_cart_conditionally( $passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
    // HERE your product categories (can be IDs, slugs or names terms)
    $terms = array( 'gekoelde-bier', 'bierkoerier');
    
    if( has_terms( $terms, 'product_cat', $product_id ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ){
        // Displaying a custom notice (optional)
        wc_add_notice( __('Only logged in users are allowed to purchase this item. Please register.'), 'error' );
        
        $passed = false;
    }
    
    return $passed;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

**2) Using `is_purchasable` product property** *(It will remove add to cart button)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable','conditional_purchasable_products', 20, 2);
function conditional_purchasable_products( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    // HERE your product categories (can be IDs, slugs or names terms)
    $terms = array( 'gekoelde-bier', 'bierkoerier');
    
    $product_id = $product->get_id(); // The product ID

    if( has_terms( $terms, 'product_cat', $product_id ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ){
        $is_purchasable = false;
    }

    return $is_purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

#### Targeting the parent product category terms too.

You will use the following custom conditional function to replace [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) Wordpress function:

```
// Custom conditional function that handle parent product categories too
function has_product_categories( $categories, $product_id = 0 ) {
    $parent_term_ids = $categories_ids = array(); // Initializing
    $taxonomy        = 'product_cat';
    $product_id      = $product_id == 0 ? get_the_id() : $product_id;

    if( is_string( $categories ) ) {
        $categories = (array) $categories; // Convert string to array
    }

    // Convert categories term names and slugs to categories term ids
    foreach ( $categories as $category ){
        $result = (array) term_exists( $category, $taxonomy );
        if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
            $categories_ids[] = reset($result);
        }
    }

    // Loop through the current product category terms to get only parent main category term
    foreach( get_the_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy ) as $term ){
        if( $term->parent > 0 ){
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->parent; // Set the parent product category
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // (and the child)
        } else {
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // It is the Main category term and we set it.
        }
    }
    return array_intersect( $categories_ids, array_unique($parent_term_ids) ) ? true : false;
}
```

Then for both hooked functions, you will replace the following line :

```
if( has_terms( $terms, 'product_cat', $product_id ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ){
```

By this line:

```
if( has_product_categories( $terms, $product_id ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ){
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it works great! I used the 3th Option.

Answer (score 1):

`woocommerce_is_purchasable` filter can do the job. It checks if a product is purchasable or not. If not purchasable, "add-to-cart" button is removed and can't be purchased.

So, here you will need to check if user is logged in or not, and product belongs to certain category, before disabling purchase ability.

This is how you can do it:

```
function wpso9800_remove_cart_button( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    //when logged in
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return $is_purchasable;
    }

    //get categories
    $categories = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat');
    $my_terms_ids = array ( 1, 2 );//product category IDs

    if ($categories && !is_wp_error($categories)) {
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            if ( in_array($cat->term_id, $my_terms_ids ) ) {
                return false;
            }
            return $is_purchasable;
        }
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable','wpso9800_remove_cart_button', 10, 2);
```

**This is tested, and working.

Note: By default, `$is_purchasable` is set to `true`. You will need to return `false`, when you want to turn off purchasing.

Comment: This one worked best for me! WooCommerce 5.8. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using option #2 because the being logged in for the listed parent categories is required. I was very careful to transfer exactly but for my site, it gives me the white screen of death. I placed this code directly in 'My Custom Functions' plugin listed under Settings>PHP Inserter. Can anyone see the problem?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable','conditional_purchasable_products', 20, 2);
function conditional_purchasable_products( $is_purchasable, $product) {
$terms= array( 'memberships', 'our-vendors', 'programs', 'uncategoriezed', 'unpublished-products');
    
$product_id= $product->get_id(); // The product ID

if( has_product_categories ( $categories, $product_id= 0) && ! is_user_logged_in() ){
        $is_purchasable= false;
    }
return $is_purchasable;
}

function has_product_categories ( $categories, $product_id = 0) {
    $parent_term_ids = $categories_ids = array(); 
    $product_id = $product_id == 0 ? get_the_id() : $product_id;
if( is_string( $categories ) ) {
        $categories = (array) $categories; 
foreach ( $categories as $category ){
        $result = (array) term_exists( $category, $taxonomy) ;
        if( ! empty( $result ) ) {
            $categories_ids[] = reset($result);
        }
    }
foreach( get_the_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy) as $term){
        if( $term->parent > 0){
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->parent;
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; 
    } else{
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; 
    }
}
    return array_intersect( $categories_ids, array_unique($parent_term_ids) ) ? true: false;
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31083661)