# Disable add-to-cart for certain categories only matches the first category in array (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have the following code to disable the add-to-cart button for products not in certain categories. However only the first category in the array is being respected.

If I have 5 categories - hats, shirts, shoes, sneakers, backpacks - It should match all of them *except* sneakers and backpacks. But it's only working for sneakers (the first in the array) - backpacks also gets the add-to-cart button disabled.

```
 function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
    // remove add-to-cart button if product is not in category "sneakers" or "backpacks"
  if( ! has_term( array( 'sneakers', 'backpacks' ), 'product_cat' ) ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
  }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 10, 2);
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong but everything I've tried doesn't make any difference :/

**References:**

- Original tutorial I followed: https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/if-product-in-category.html
- https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/the-right-way-to-hide-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce/

**Also tried:**

`if( ! is_product_category( array( 'sneakers', 'backpacks'))) {` but this disabled ALL add-to-cart buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the second example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53058011/5204226 works (I had to change `has_terms` to `has_term`).

```
function conditional_purchasable_products( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    // HERE your product categories (can be IDs, slugs or names terms)
    $terms = array( 'sneakers', 'backpacks');

    $product_id = $product->get_id(); // The product ID

    if( ! has_term( $terms, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
        $is_purchasable = false;
    }

    return $is_purchasable;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable','conditional_purchasable_products', 20, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

- you must `return` a `$value`, so `return` is missing
- `woocommerce_is_purchasable` has 2 parameters, `$value` & `$product`. however, these are empty in your code

Give it a try this way

```php
function remove_add_to_cart_buttons( $value, $product ) {
    // remove add-to-cart button if product is not in category "sneakers" or "backpacks"
    if( ! has_term( array( 'sneakers', 'backpacks' ), 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $value = false;
    }

    return $value;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Would that not make products (not in sneakers and backpacks categories) disappear altogether? I just want to remove the add to cart button. My understanding of `woocommerce_is_purchasable` is that it returns a boolean.